# Time calculator in C

Tags: c, time, calculator, hour

I have to write a time calculator in C language.

I just write normal calculator:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char operator;
float firstNumber,secondNumber;

printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *,): ");
scanf("%c", &operator);

printf("Enter two operands: ");
scanf("%f %f",&firstNumber, &secondNumber);

switch(operator)
{
    case '+':
        printf("%0.2f + %0.2f = %0.2f\n",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber + secondNumber);
        break;

    case '-':
        printf("%0.2f - %0.2f = %0.2f\n",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber - secondNumber);
        break;

    case '*':
        printf("%0.2f * %0.2f = %0.2f\n",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber * secondNumber);
        break;

    case '/':
        printf("%0.2f / %0.2f = %0.2f\n",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber / secondNumber);
        break;

    // operator doesn't match any case constant (+, -, *, /)
    default:
        printf("Error! operator is not correct");
}

return 0;
}
```

I need to prepare a time calculator, e.g.:

> 17,58 + 0,12 = 18,10
>
> 17,58 / 2 = 8,59
>
> 0,15 * 4 = 1.00

Could you help me, please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to see how you ask about what.

Comment: lets just say, floating point numbers are not the best choice when you plan to calculate with accurate hour/minute/second values.

Comment: I would convert the input time in minutes, process the operations (as standard operation), and convert the result from minutes to time.

Comment: 17,58 mean 17 hour and 58 minute?

Comment: Yes, 17,58 mean 17:58. 17 hour and 58 minute

Comment: https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/src/#dateexpr

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that function, you should write 2 function

1. convert from float (such as 17.58) to total of minute (17 * 60 + 58 = 1078)
2. convert from total of minute to float

Example:

```
#include <math.h>
int float2minute(float time)
{
    int hour = (int) floor(time);
    int minute = (time - hour) * 100;
    return hour * 60 + minute;
}

float minute2float(int time)
{
    float hour = floor((float)time / 60);
    float minute = time - hour * 60;
    return hour + minute / 100;
}
```

Now, you can use 2 above function as:

```
printf("%0.2f + %0.2f = %0.2f\n",firstNumber, secondNumber, minute2float(float2minute(firstNumber) + float2minute(secondNumber)));
```